POST request with nodejs and express 500 error
So I am building a full stack app and my get method works fine and my ui can access it no issues but now I have a problem with my POST request when trying to write back to the server(this is running on an internal intranet). I get a 500 internal error and a large dump of information when I throw the correct url at Thunderclient
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'firstName' of 'req.body' as it is undefined.    at C:\CFusionMX7\wwwroot\TimeCard\server.js:65:13    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\CFusionMX7\wwwroot\TimeCard\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)    at next (C
It kind of goes on like that for about three times that length.
I have tried to write and rewrite this a few times now. I was getting a 404 not found and I realized my url was incorrect and that when you use thunderclient to get a POST request you actually have to select POST from the dropdown(doh!)
Anyways my server side code is as follows.
apiRouter.post('/create-timecard', (req, res) => {   
const { firstName, lastName, employeeId } = req.body;
const today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
const timeCardFileName = `${today}_${employeeId}.txt`;

// Write the content of the time card file
fs.writeFile(`./TimeCard/database/${timeCardFileName}`, '', (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error creating time card:', err);
        res.status(500).send('Error creating time card');
        return;
    }
    res.send({ message: 'Time card created successfully', timeCardFileName });
});
});


You try to descruct const { firstName, lastName, employeeId } = req.body and req.body does not find firstName. The Request body is a simple string. Therefore body (JSON) parsers exist. I think you can solve this issue if you parse your body into a JSON or JS Object before you try to distruct it into single variables.

Ensure that you have the body-parser middleware set up in your Express app to parse incoming request bodies.
npm install body-parser

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

